# get most recent posts using facebook search api

Tags: facebook-graph-api, post

I want to get recent posts[wall post/video/image] using Facebook API/graph API.
I have searched for that and i have founded that i can get recent activity but for particular user only.

But I want to get all the recent public posts from Facebook not for any particular user.
Is this possible?

Thanking in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Graph API search command.  It does what you want.  It's documented nearly at the end of the main Graph API documentation page.

Comment: hey thank for your reply.it gives me result for particular user or particular page.. but i want to get all the public posts. not based on any query or search term or any user id. i want to get all the most recent posts[updates] from facebook.  is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: The Graph API search command does public posts please see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/ "Search" section. However, you must specify a search term. "You can search over all public objects in the social graph with https://graph.facebook.com/search. The format is:

https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=QUERY&type=OBJECT_TYPE
"